# Word for a compliment that is disguised as a question

Tags: questions, compliment

A term for question that is asked in public with intention to make the questioner or the person being asked appear in a better light.

As an example, a question asked in British parliament to the Prime minister from the member of the same party, complimenting the prime minister via the question itself.

Comment: Your first sentence asks about making the *speaker* look better, but then your parliament example is about the speaker complimenting the *other* person. Which do you mean?

Comment: Can you add substance to the question? There's nothing here that is a compliment in a question.

Comment: I have clarified my question slightly. The accepted answer below mentioning 'sycophantic question' is the term I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a noun meaning 'a flattering question asked in public'.

Such a question asked in parliament, according to [Shane Martin and Olivier Rozenberg](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JX-3AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=PM%27s%20questions.%20What%20are%20the%20sycophantic%20questions%20called?&source=bl&ots=EszaYnMgJ2&sig=ACfU3U1B_sFhUVSaZ0-i2GI8Oaq4Lj2fyA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_k5PUyfzlAhWDsHEKHdxdD_kQ6AEwDnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=PM's%20questions.%20What%20are%20the%20sycophantic%20questions%20called%3F&f=false) is simply called a sycophantic question.

You may have looked at a thesaurus already but here are the entries for the adjective [obsequious](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/obsequious) and the verb and noun [toady](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/toady). Unfortunately the nouns are names for the toady himself, not his question, so you won't find your single word there.

Private Eye's invented term Arslikhan may be what you're looking for. It is written with an upper case A to mean the state, and a lower case one to mean its best-known product: much like 'China' and 'china'.

Here's an example from *Lord Gnome's Literary Companion*, by Francis Wheen, 1996, page 226:

> "As this passage suggests, Masters is a graduate of the Arslikhan
>   school of biography."